# Venn diagram word problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a group of 100, 50 are having an umbrella, 60 have a hat and 80 have sunglasses. 70 are such that they don’t have both – an umbrella and a hat. Similarly 50 are such that they do not have both hat and sunglasses and 60 do not have both umbrellas and sunglasses. If there are 5 who do not own any  of the three items, find the number of people who own all three items.

I couldn't solve the question using 2 equations 
those who wear exactly one of the three  -n (A ) + n (B ) + n (C ) - 2 (n (A ∩ B ) + n (B ∩ C ) + n (A ∩ C )) + 3 × n (A ∩ B ∩ C )
and the general formula to find the union -
n (A ) + n (B ) + n (C ) - n (A ∩ B ) - n (B ∩ C ) - n (A ∩ C ) .

I took the sum of 70 , 50 , 60 as the sum of those who wear exactly one of the three
and 95 as the union

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I would always draw a diagram for a question like this. I find it rather easy to get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set of people who own an umbrella, $B$ be the set of people who own a hat, and $C$ be the set of people who own sunglasses. We want to compute the number of people who own all three items, which is equal to $|A \cap B \cap C|.$

The Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion asserts

$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |B \cap C| - |A \cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|. $$

Here, $|A| = 50, |B| = 60, $ and $|C| = 80$. Also, we know there are $70$ people who are *not* in the set $A \cap B$, which means that there are $100 - 70 = 30$ people in this set. Thus, $|A \cap B| = 30$. Using similar reasoning, we can find $|B \cap C| = 50$ and $|A \cap C| = 40$. Also, we know $|A \cup B \cup C| = 5$ for the reason you described. Therefore,

$$|A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |B \cap C| - |A \cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|  $$

$$5= 50 + 60 + 80 - 30 - 50 - 40 - |A \cap B \cap C|   $$

$$\implies |A \cap B \cap C| = \boxed{65} $$

Comment: Well the answer given for this particular problem is 25